# Change \caption behaviour

Tags: xetex, captions

I am messing around with `\caption` package and what I need is to place `\figurename` after figure numbering and change it to be *att.*, basicly what I need is:
*1.2 att.* **figure text**
I managed to put `\figurename` after this number, but I can't get rid of the one that is before, and for some reason renaming is not working ("Att." is default `\figurename` for my language set with babel, but I want it to start with small "a"). Here is minimal example:

```
% XeLaTeX is used to compile this
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,latvian]{article}
% Latvian language support
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian}
% For tikz graphics
\usepackage{tikz}
% Captions
\usepackage[labelfont=it, textfont=bf]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure} \figurename}

\begin{document}
%...
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{figure text}
\end{figure}
%...
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

---

**UPDATE**
Figured out renaming problem. Since I'm using latvian (or other non-english language) here is how to do renaming:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=it, textfont=bf]{caption}
\addto\captionslatvian{
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure} \figurename}
}
```

Still have troubles with first "att."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal example? Are you loading `babel` for Latvian?

Comment: I will update this shortly with minimal example. Figured out renaming. Still troubles with positioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a label format for Latvian:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{latvian}{#2 #1}
\captionsetup{labelfont=it,textfont=bf,labelformat=latvian}
\appto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\Huge X
\caption{Pašreizēja trajektorijas veidošana un rēala spēja to izlidot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]